# UWP StoreProductQueryResult returns no products

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

We are unable to return a list of add-on products for our Windows Store app.

We have an app in the Windows Store with 3 subscription add-ons.The add-ons are marked as Hidden as we don't want them visible in the store, only through our app.

We are developing a new version of our app which targets Windows 16299. We are using the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace.

However this code only returns one of the list of add-ons

```
if (context == null)
    context = StoreContext.GetDefault();

string[] productKinds = { "Durable" };
List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);

StoreProductQueryResult queryResult = await context.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(filterList);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StoreProduct> addOn in queryResult.Products)
{
    StoreProduct product = addOn.Value;
    AddOnList.Add(product);
}
```

`ExtendedError = null`
Why does this code only return one of the list of add-on products? 
The products have been certified and are listed as In The Store.

Comment: Has your addon submission passed certification and been in the Store?

It could take some time to get updated for the addon after your new package gets into the Store.

Comment: Check this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/157004/storecontextgetassociatedstoreproductsasync-with-1.html

Comment: As I said in my question @Gaurang Dave The products have been certified and are listed as In The Store. Also the issue is not with a property of a returned product but that no products are returned.

Comment: +1 for @Gaurang Dave ... even though the add-ons were listed as In The Store, it took another 24 hours for the first of them to be returned in a query. I guess now it is only a matter of time before the rest of them appear.

Comment: Answering the same below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micorsoft App store takes some time (approx. 24 hours) to enable the products/add-ons (some time apps as well) to programming APIs. It happened to me while getting products in my app very long time ago.

Always make sure that It could take some time to get updated for the addon/product after your new package gets into the Store.

I got something worth to look for getting add-on/product via API. Check [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/157004/storecontextgetassociatedstoreproductsasync-with-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

This happens for existing app in the store. You need create a new uwp certificate every year and if you create a new certificate and you changed the publisher or issued by fields by mistake on your pfx file, ad-ons are no longer returned.