# UWP StoreProductQueryResult returns no products when products are in the store

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

This question is a follow up of my earlier question from some years ago [UWP StoreProductQueryResult returns no products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061510/uwp-storeproductqueryresult-returns-no-products)

The product and the list of add-ons have now been in the store for some years. When installed from the store the following line of code returns 20 add-ons.

```
string[] productKinds = { "Durable" };
List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);
StoreProductQueryResult queryResult = await storeContext.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(filterList);
```

I have a new dev machine and in debug this line of code returns 0 add-ons.

**EDIT:** I have associated the app with the store.

What am I missing in setting up my dev machine for UWP development?

Comment: Have you [associated your app with Microsoft store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/step-1--create-a-uwp-device-app#associate-your-app-with-the-microsoft-store) ?

Comment: Yes I have associate the app with the store

Comment: What product kind string you have passed ?

Comment: string[] productKinds = { "Durable" };
List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds); The code running in debug is the code that was published to the store

Comment: For this problem,  only the store team could check your app's state, I'd suggest you open a free support ticket here: [Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/). Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic, and select App submissions and management for issue type.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Why would there be a problem with the state of the app in the store? It's been in the store for years and installs without issue. The issue is gettng it to run on my machine in debug.

Comment: it's hard to say, it may related with the network or os version etc, because we can't reproduce  your problem,  and we also can't check your store app's status so we suggest your open support ticket.

Comment: Forgive me @NicoZhu-MSFT but in the past we've raised tickets with the store and wasted a lot of time repeating the details to endlessly changing staff and ultimately given up in despair. Anything but that. This app runs in debug on other dev machines, so I think it is unlikely to be a store issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240120/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-vague).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP StoreProductQueryResult returns no products when products are in the store

After discuss with Vague, if we run the app in release mode, it will re-generated another certificate. then used that certificate in debug and it ran perfectly and get add-ons successfully.